# Visual Studio stop running the application once I start

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using MVC5 with C# application but what my problem is VS 2013 and VS 2015 immediately stops whenever I try to run the application. Output window is showing the below message:

The program '[8916] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[8916] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: From your return code your application finished successfully, what was it supposed to do? Have you tried running in inside a console to see any potential output?

Comment: No. How to run the web application in console

Comment: Try running the default MVC application, to see if the probleme come from configuration problemme on vs, vs's test web serveur or your code.

Comment: Problem solved for me. I uncheck the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox from web tab in the properties of my application.